# filter and remove empty columns from multiple table

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter

I am using the [tty-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tty-table) plugin to print a table in my console application

The actual result of table contains many columns with somes contains "0" as a data , see example below

| Product | Stock | Country | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Samsung S20 | 0 | Germany | 0 |
| Iphone 13 | 0 | England | 0 |
| Samsung A71 | 0 | US | 0 |
| SOne | 0 | UK | 0 |

I would like to hide columns that have 0 as data for all the rows.
Result should be:

| Product | Country |
| --- | --- |
| Samsung S20 | Germany |
| Iphone 13 | England |
| Samsung A71 | US |
| SOne | UK |

In my code each row is an array, so the result of rows is an array of arrays : example

```js
[
["Samsung S20",0,"Germany",0],
["Iphone 13",0,"England",0],
["Samsung A71",0,"US",0],
["SOne",0,"UK",0],
]
```

Can you help me to have something like this :

```js
[
["Samsung S20","Germany"],
["Iphone 13","England"],
["Samsung A71","US"],
["SOne","UK"],
]
```

**Important:** The header of table is an array of objects :

```js
[{value:"Product"} , {value:"Stock"} ,{value:"Country"} ,{value:"Price"} }
```

the appearance of columns depends on their existing on the header array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way but one option would be to construct a table excluding the zero sum columns, then extract the headers and rows to feed into tty-table:

```js
let headers = [
  { value: "Product" },
  { value: "Stock" },
  { value: "Country" },
  { value: "Price" }
]

let rows = [
  ["Samsung S20", 0, "Germany", 0],
  ["Iphone 13", 0, "England", 0],
  ["Samsung A71", 0, "US", 0],
  ["SOne", 0, "UK", 0],
]

let table = headers
  .map((h, index) => ({header: h.value, values: rows.map(sub => sub[index])}))
  .filter(item => item.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) !== 0)

let newHeaders = table.map(item => ({value: item.header}))

let tableRows = table.map(arr => arr.values)
let newRows = tableRows[0].map((_, c) => tableRows.map(row => row[c]))

console.log(newHeaders)
console.log(newRows)
```

Comment: Nice approach, but In your code, you're removing the header if all the rows for a column are zero, which I think is correct, but then when you create `newRows` you are removing a column from a single row if the item is `0`. That means if you had a column that had all `0`s except one row that had a `1`, then the header for the column would still exist, but each row that had a zero would be removed and hence "shifted" to the left by one. One small change I would also suggest is to swap the first and last `reduce` methods with `.map()`, as you're effectively doing a mapping operation with both

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons! Good catch. I have updated my answer.